# Finite geometric series demonstration issue

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I want to demonstrate that:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n q^k = \frac{1-q^{n+1}}{1-q}$$
with sums properties.
It can be written as:
$$(1-q)\sum_{k=0}^n q^k = 1-q^{n+1}$$
Where:
$$(1-q)\sum_{k=0}^n q^k = \sum_{k=0}^n q^k -q\sum_{k=0}^n q^k$$
then:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n q^k -q\sum_{k=0}^n q^k=\sum_{k=0}^n q^k -\sum_{k=0}^n q^{k+1}=\sum_{k=0}^n q^k -\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} q^k$$
I don't understand how, according to sum properties, $\sum_{k=0}^n q^k -\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} q^k$ can be rewritten as:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n q^k -\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} q^k=1+\sum_{k=1}^{n}q^k- \left( \sum_{k=1}^n q^k+q^{n+1} \right)=1-q^{n+1}$$

Comment: Are you asking why the last line holds? The $k=0$ term is taken out of $\sum_{k=0}^n q^k$, and similarly $k=n+1$ term is taken out of $\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} q^k$ (so the remaining sums are both ranging from $1$ to $n$).

Comment: Hi Barbab. It all looks good. Maybe you are missing that $q^0=1$. By the way, for any complex numbers $a,b$ a similar proof shows that $(a-b)\sum_{k=0}^n a^k\,b^{n-k}= a^{n+1}-b^{n+1}$.

Comment: Ok so it is $\sum_{k=0}^n q^k = q^0 + \sum_{k=1}^n q^k$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} q^k = \sum_{k=1}^n q^k + q^{n+1}$? If it is so I understand :) thank you

Comment: @Barbab Exactly. If sigma (sum) notation gets in a way, you can always write it as $q^0+q^1+\dots+q^n=q^0+(q^1+\dots+q^n)$ for example, it is the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first sum we start from $ k=1 $ but we add the term that we get for $ k=0 $, so the sum doesn't change:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n q^k = q^0+\sum_{k=1}^n q^k=1+\sum_{k=1}^n q^k$$

For the second sum we arrive up to $k=n$ but we add the term that we get for $ k=n+1 $, so the sum doesn't change:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} q^k=\sum_{k=1}^n q^k+q^{n+1} $$

Then subtracting the expressions we have just calculated, we get your expression.